# Allocate array of struct and then access it using an array method give compilation error

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I allocate structs array and tried to access elements using the array indexer syntax `ptr[i]->a` but it doesn't work.

On the other hand, when I use pointer arithmetic `(ptr + i)->a` it works.

The reason why I try to access using the array method is that I thought that struct allocated continuously in heap memory.

Is my assumption wrong?

Could anyone tell me the reason?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sample_t{
    int a;
} Sample;

void Function(Sample *ptr)
{
    int i;
    Sample *tmp = ptr;
    for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
    { 
        (tmp + i)->a = i; //work!!
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
    { 
        ptr[i]->a = i;    //doesn't work!!
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Sample *arr = (Sample *)calloc(100, sizeof(Sample));
    Function(arr);
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misreading something, you need `ptr[i].a = i;` — `ptr[i]` is a `Sample`, not a pointer to a `Sample`.  You say "doesn't work", but you don't say in what it doesn't work.

Comment: "the reason why I try to access using the array method is that I thought that struct allocated continuously in heap memory." yes, but it won't give you the best performance due to alignment and padding between struct members. This does not apply to your case though.

Comment: Can you tell us what "doesn't work" means?  It crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My compiler says:

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Sample' {aka 'sample_t'}
```

I'm sure yours says something similar.  It's complaining about this:

```
    ptr[i]->a = i;
```

So it's saying `ptr[i]` is not a pointer (which `->` requires).  And `ptr[i]` is not a pointer because `ptr[i]` in C is equivalent to `*(ptr + i)` which means the dereferencing of the incremented pointer already happened, so you'd need this instead:

```
    ptr[i].a = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

An array subscript expression is automatically dereferenced for you, so you don't need to use `->` to access members, use `.` instead.

Because `ptr[offset]` is the same as `*(ptr + offset)` (note the required dereference `*` in the latter, but not the former).

So change this:

```
ptr[i]->a = i;
```

To this:

```
ptr[i].a = i;
```

---

BTW, when working with dynamically-allocated arrays in C you should always keep the length of the array with the array-pointer itself (in C++ you'd use `std::array` for this). Don't forget to use `size_t` for the length instead of `int`.

e.g.

```
void Function( size_t n, Sample* arr )
```